# Location of default image button in android?

Tags: android

Does anyone know where I can find the default image used for button in android? It will be a nine-patch with the .9.png extensions.

Answer (score 2):

You will find it in the android.jar file in your sdk folder.

For example mine is in 
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-8\android.jar
    (for SDK version 8, to get a different version the change the "android-8" part of the path)

You can extract the .jar using winzip/7z etc as it is just a zip file in disguise. You will then find the drawables folder in the folders you unzipped.

Answer (score 2):

Find in the drawable-* folders in the following path

C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-*\data\res